# How to fill a cell in a specific sheet with data of new Google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet called "metrics" with one row for each day, for example:

```
day           counts1  counts2  counts3
01-01-2019
01-02-2019
01-03-2019
01-04-2019
01-05-2019
...
```

Each day I create a new sheet called the same as the date. For example, in 01-06-2019 I create a sheet called "01-06-2019" and enter data into it. With this daily data, I calculate for each day counts1, counts2 and counts3.

I want to fill the sheet "metrics" with those values adding a new row and the corresponding counts1, counts2, counts3.

Or, is it another better way to save the data and achieve this goal?

Comment: @player0 How can I upload a file?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3DDV.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBGnH.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DE2yH.png with "can edit" would be good

Comment: @player0 : thanks, here it goes: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wj9WN2x1sfKV5OoqTI7witi7VNC7WkqAyOPybKlSq1I/edit?usp=sharing   The thing is that I have to create one sheet per day and register the data in another sheet "metrics"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### paste in B2 cell and drag down the small blue square

```
={SUM(    INDIRECT(TO_TEXT(A2)&"!B2:C2")),
  AVERAGE(INDIRECT(TO_TEXT(A2)&"!C2:C")),
  SUM(    INDIRECT(TO_TEXT(A2)&"!B2:B"))}
```

[image]

### to create sheets/tabs you can use this script:

```
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('NEW DAY')
        .addItem('Create New Tabs', 'createTabs')
        .addToUi()
}

function createTabs() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    ss.getSheetByName('metrics').getRange('A2:A').getValues().filter(String)
        .forEach(function (sn) {
            if (!ss.getSheetByName(sn[0])) {
                ss.insertSheet(sn[0], ss.getSheets().length);
            }
        })
}
```

- add this script
- reload spreadsheet with <kbd>F5</kbd>
- select column A
- click on <kbd>123</kbd> button
- and select **`Plain text`**
- add new days in column A
- then click on **NEW DAY**
- select **Create New Tabs**

this will automatically create new tabs from a list of dates in A column by skipping already created tabs/sheets and also skipping empty cells

[image]

---

to avoid typing in dates each time, use this formula in **A2** cell and drag down:

```
=TO_TEXT(TEXT(DATE(2019, 1, 1)+ROW()-2, "MM-dd-yyyy"))
```

### how to add a script to your spreadsheet

- go to **Tools**
- select **Script editor**

  [image: 0]
- copy paste the script
- save the project under some name

  [image]
- click on run icon and authorise it...

  [image]
- select your account

  [image]
- click on **Advanced**

  [image]
- select **Go to * (unsafe)**

  [image]
- click on **Allow** and return to your sheet (you can close script window/tab)

  [image]

Comment: @Laura let me know if you don't know how to add script to your spreadsheet

Comment: Amazing @player0 thanks! I just have one error when I click in NEWDAY: something about permissions: This app isn't verified
This app hasn't been verified by Google yet. Only proceed if you know and trust the developer.

If you’re the developer, submit a verification request to remove ...

Comment: yup, ignore it click on `Advanced` scroll down and click on `Go to * (unsafe)`

Comment: Ah ok! And Is it safe if I use it for a company? Should I take some caution about the data?

Comment: Hi @player0 I have a last question about this. with this script I create new empty sheets automatically.  Is there a way to create the new spreadsheets with info? I mean, with the columns "case", "data1", "data2"...   and the cells "counts1-3" ?

If this could be done, can I add (in addition) in each new sheet , info which is in the previous day (and only there) sheet?

Comment: yes, it's highly possible, but unfortunately beyond my skills (I am not good with scripts at all)